# How useful is pre-approval from multiple lenders?

Tags: loans

How useful is it to get pre-approval from multiple lenders on a home loan?  Is it really possible to find better rates this way?

Answer (score 2):

Pre-approval doesn't really help you on getting a better interest rate. It just show the seller that you are a more serious buyer and less likely to drop out of the deal late in the game because you couldn't get financing.

In fact, there is a chance that it may HURT your chance of getting a good rate because each lender will do a hard pull on your credit report which will temporarily reduce your credit score, which lenders use to decide whether to give you a good rate.

Answer (score 1):

It may be a good idea to have a backup option.  This way if borrower discovers the first lender has unreasonable fees of or makes unreasonable requests during the underwriting process, the borrower has some freedom.

If your hard credit pulls for a mortgage or auto loan are around the same time, the credit rating agencies recognize it as shopping around.  See this article from Experian, one of the three major credit rating agencies: https://www.experian.com/blogs/ask-experian/multiple-inquiries-when-shopping-for-an-car-loan/